Create Add-In for PPT which creates a timer textbox
I want to create an Add-In, which creates a button into the toolbox of PowerPoint. When pressing the button, it should create two textboxes. One of the textboxes should call the macro "countdown" when clicking the textbox.
My two functions CreateTimer() and countdown() work, when the module is open in the current presentation. Also the Button is added to the toolbox when running the Add-In. When clicking the button the two textboxes are created as intended. The only problem is: Nothing happens when I click on the textbox
What is wrong with my code?
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim oToolbar As CommandBar
    Dim oButton As CommandBarButton
    Dim MyToolbar As String

    ' Give the toolbar a name
    MyToolbar = "AddTimer"

    On Error Resume Next
    ' so that it doesn't stop on the next line if the toolbar's already there

    ' Create the toolbar; PowerPoint will error if it already exists
    Set oToolbar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=MyToolbar, _
        Position:=msoBarFloating, Temporary:=True)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          ' The toolbar's already there, so we have nothing to do
          Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Now add a button to the new toolbar
    Set oButton = oToolbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)

    ' And set some of the button's properties

    With oButton

         .DescriptionText = "Adds a timer to the current slide"
          'Tooltip text when mouse if placed over button

         .Caption = ""
         'Text if Text in Icon is chosen

         .OnAction = "CreateTimer"
          'Runs the Sub Button1() code when clicked

         .Style = msoButtonIcon
          ' Button displays as icon, not text or both

         .FaceId = 52
          ' chooses icon #52 from the available Office icons

    End With

    ' Repeat the above for as many more buttons as you need to add
    ' Be sure to change the .OnAction property at least for each new button

    ' You can set the toolbar position and visibility here if you like
    ' By default, it'll be visible when created. Position will be ignored in PPT 2007 and later
    oToolbar.Top = 150
    oToolbar.Left = 150
    oToolbar.Visible = True

NormalExit:
    Exit Sub   ' so it doesn't go on to run the errorhandler code

ErrorHandler:
     'Just in case there is an error
     MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
     Resume NormalExit:
End Sub



Sub CreateTimer()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim countdownTextbox As Shape
    Dim timeInputTextbox As Shape
    Dim slideWidth As Single
    Dim slideHeight As Single
    Dim textboxWidth As Single
    Dim textboxHeight As Single
    Dim leftPosition As Single
    Dim topPosition As Single
    Dim time As Date
    Dim count As Integer
    
    
    ' Get the reference to the current slide
    Set slide = ActiveWindow.View.slide
    
    ' Get the width and height of the slide
    slideWidth = slide.Master.Width
    slideHeight = slide.Master.Height
    
    ' Create countdown textbox
    textboxWidth = 200 ' Adjust as needed
    textboxHeight = 50 ' Adjust as needed
    leftPosition = (slideWidth - textboxWidth) / 2
    topPosition = (slideHeight - textboxHeight) / 2
    Set countdownTextbox = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, leftPosition, topPosition, textboxWidth, textboxHeight)
    countdownTextbox.Name = "countdown"
    With countdownTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "" ' Empty text
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red font color
        .Font.Size = 72 ' Font size 72
    End With
    With countdownTextbox
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse ' No outline
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse ' No fill
    End With
    countdownTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange = Format(180, "nn:ss") ' 180 seconds as an example
    
    ' Create time input textbox
    textboxWidth = 80 ' Adjust as needed
    textboxHeight = 20 ' Adjust as needed
    leftPosition = slideWidth + 20
    topPosition = slideHeight - textboxHeight - 20
    Set timeInputTextbox = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, leftPosition, topPosition, textboxWidth, textboxHeight)
    timeInputTextbox.Name = "timeinput"
    timeInputTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "180"  ' 180 seconds as an example
    
    
    
    slide.Shapes("countdown").ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Run = "countdown"
    
End Sub



Public Sub countdown()
'source: https://pptvba.com/powerpoint-insert-countdown-timer-vba-tutorial/
'https://24slides.com/presentbetter/powerpoint-countdown-timer

Dim time As Date
time = Now()

Dim count As Integer

count = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.slide.Shapes("timeinput").TextFrame.TextRange  'Change time value in text field

time = DateAdd("s", count, time)

Do Until time < Now()
DoEvents
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.slide.Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "nn:ss")
Loop

End Sub



I googled a lot but haven't found a solution so far.
How do I need to adapt my code.

Are you trying to get this to work in normal view? That won't happen. When I tried in slide show view, the counter starts when clicked. However, if you close the show before the timer runs out, an error occurs  on the line just prior to Loop. Also, if you click the button again, another shape gets added; you should include code to check for an existing counter shape and delete it before adding one.

The same is true for: On Error Resume Next    ' so that it doesn't stop on the next line if the toolbar's already there.   It is much better to remove the toolbar (in NormalExit`, or wherever that should be done), than to stop being able to debug your own code....

@Luuk Good point. That'd be in an Auto_Close subroutine.
